# How to set graph origin in corner of graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I would like for the origin of my graph to start in the corner of the X,Y axis. As it is, the origin is set off from the origin. I also would not mind to get rid of those ticks.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
my style, 
legend pos=north east
xmajorticks=false, 
ymajorticks=false, 
xticklabels={,,}
xmin=0, xmax=5, ymin=0, ymax=5,
]
\addplot[domain=0:4] {x}, xmajorticks=false;

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TeX-SE! You can achieve this with `axis lines=middle`. For the future, please provide us with complete documents that start with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`. Then those who are willing to answer the question will not have to make up a preamble. In this case, I have really no clue what `dharmic` is. In any case, I think you are looking for `axis lines=middle`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,
% dharmic, 
% legend pos=north east
xmajorticks=false, 
ymajorticks=false, 
xticklabels={,,},
xmajorticks=false,
xmin=0, xmax=5, ymin=0, ymax=5,
]
\addplot[domain=0:4] {x};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]